# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, string, mysqli, type-conversion, runtime-error

My problem isn't the same as the other questions, I use a dramatically different code which I'm not sure how to deal with or how to apply solutions of others' codes to mine.

I am getting the error

```
Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in
```

This is the part where my code has problems

```
    <?php
function aggiornamento($utente){
global $conn;
global $_CONFIG;
           $selezione=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ".$_CONFIG['db_account'].".account WHERE login = '".$utente."' LIMIT 1");
           while ($account = mysqli_fetch_array($selezione))
           {
    $_SESSION['IShop_Login']= $account['login'];
           }
} ?>
```

Whereas line 5 is the "faulty" line

Comment: can someone tell me how to get rid of this error.....

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
```

try to connect first with you db and then use it like

```
$selezione=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ".$_CONFIG['db_account'].".account WHERE login = '".$utente."' LIMIT 1");
           while ($account = mysqli_fetch_array($selezione))
```

you can refer link

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

we have procedural style of `mysqli_query`

Hope this solves your query

Comment: ok if you have already done this then i think there is problem with variables used in query...i think you should check it's values first...try to print value of '$selezione' i think if it return false then print only query on output window...without mysqli_query tag, you will understand what values have been passed....

Comment: without mysqli_query tag it gives unexpected ',' i error.. with it unchanged and echo $selezione; nothing appears... when i open the file in browser..maybe i need to debug or something?

Comment: nothing appers means false that means you query creating problem or may be if your query is right then there is connection problem. Now my suggestion is check first query i think use this like 
`mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM '".$_CONFIG['db_account']."'account WHERE login = '".$utente."' LIMIT 1");`
i.e. see `$_CONFIG` i have changed inverted commas

Comment: can you please let me what is `account` in your query as you have used '.' after giving database name??? i think you have appended `.account` after  db name???

Comment: do like 

`echo "SELECT * FROM '".$_CONFIG['db_account']."'.account WHERE login = '".$utente."' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: and post here your output

Comment: still nothing appears..i may be doing it wrong but if u want to know the value $_CONFIG['db_account'] holds it is account as defined in config.php $_CONFIG['db_account'] = "account"; so basically its account.account where login "a table field that already exists in account"..

Comment: hey it actually appeared.. heres the output SELECT * FROM 'account'.account WHERE login = 'shoptest' LIMIT 1

Comment: ok then remove single quote like this copy it

`SELECT * FROM ".$_CONFIG['db_account'].".account WHERE login = '".$utente."' LIMIT 1`

Comment: still the same and even got  another error...ive seen many questions with the same problem and their solutions revolved around totally different things from what ur discussing anyway.. for example while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['classtype']."<br>";
    } anyway im tired maybe ill look up on google and forget here for a while since nobody knows how to do it anywany but thanks for ur efforts at least u tried ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`,

```
while ($account = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selezione))
{
    $_SESSION['IShop_Login']= $account['login'];
}
```

Comment: It gives the following warnings:
Notice: Undefined variable: selezione in on line 6

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in on line 6

Answer (score 0):

The error is in:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "... WHERE login = '". $utente ."' LIMIT 1";
```

where `$utente` is expected to be a string, but it is instance of `mysqli`, i.e. connection. Have a look at what you are passing to this `function aggiornamento($utente)` and make sure you pass string (with login / username) instead of connection.

Comment: I'm not the original author of the code, but i can't see anything passed to that function actually, other than only being present in this code i wrote. a beginner here.. :P

Comment: @P4P4DR4G0N: Code you pasted in your question shows the definition of the function. Problem is in its usage.

Comment: Well it used to work fine like 3-4 months ago before most functions/variables deprecated and i had to take a good care of them again. after i updated the deprecated things, errors like this started to show up:/